# iPad adHoc app limitation

Tags: xcode, asihttprequest, adhoc

My client wants to use AdHoc iPad app. (don't want to go through app submission)
I want to know there's any limitation if i use AdHoc app.

1. Do i need to reinstall the app to every devices every 3 months? (the profile will be expired every three months)
2. I want to use ASIHTTPRequest to retrieve update datas from web server. Can I do that on AdHoc app and etc

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit of 100 devices. More info at: http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html

Ad Hoc Distribution

"With Ad Hoc distribution you can share your application with up to 100 other iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch users. Through email or by posting it to a website or server, users can download and install your app."

1. Yes, re-installation will be required.
2. Yes, data can be fetched from the server.

Comment: I also think (but can't find clear written confirmation of this) that you can't have a working in-app purchase system in an Ad Hoc app. Can somebody confirm that?

Comment: @DirtyHenry Yes in Ad Hoc builds, in-app purchase functionality only works in 'sandbox' environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

"Distribute your proprietary, in-house iOS apps to employees or members of your organization. You can also securely host and wirelessly distribute or update in-house apps to employees, keeping them current anywhere, anytime."

Make sure to read "Terms & Conditions" closely as Apple may allow enterprise apps for employees only.

Comment: Thanks.. my client doesn't want to use Enterprise program.